# 2sxc custom API return list of entities

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a field set up as entity, with multiple items selectable.

I have the following API part:

```
[HttpPost]
    public TriggerDetails returnTriggerInfo([FromBody] string CatId)
    {
       var returnTriggerDetails = new TriggerDetails();
       
       var CatList = AsList(App.Data["Categories"]);
       var myCat = CatList.Where(a => a.EntityId.ToString() == CatId.ToString());
       if (myCat.Count() == 1)
       {
            var thisCat = myCat.First();
            returnTriggerDetails.CatName = thisCat.CatName;
            returnTriggerDetails.Level = thisCat.Level;
            returnTriggerDetails.Registry = thisCat.Registry;
            returnTriggerDetails.Trigger = AsList(thisCat.Trigger); // Need help here. This is the field set up as entity
       }
        
        return returnTriggerDetails;
    }

public class TriggerDetails {
    public string CatName {get;set;}
    public string Level {get;set;}
    public string Registry {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Trigger {get;set;} // Need help here too
}
```

Which needs to return that same field without specifying the contents of the original entity (the fields from the linked entity).
How can I cast this so that the entire contents of fields "Trigger" in "Categories" are returned?

Comment: Can you outline what .Trigger is? I assume this is the Entity and `thisCat.Trigger` may contain 0, 1, or Many of the target content-type. But can you be more specific about what you expect `returnTriggerDetails.Trigger to contain/return? It seems like you may just need to use something like `= (thisCat.Trigger as Dynlist).Select(t => t.This as ...)` so you are just returning the needed fields in an AsList()?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you seem to want to have the "whole Entity" of `thisCat.Trigger` serialized - is that correct?

> Note: in general you would probably prefer to do something like this in a VisualQuery

Just FYI: Entities don't really serialize well the way you may think, because they are multi-language internally.

The simplest way is to use our converter

https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Conversion.DataToDictionary.html

Create a converter object, then just call `converter.Convert(yourEntity)` which should give you a simple object which will work well in auto-serialization.

Comment: Note that there is a simple example using this here: https://docs.2sxc.org/web-api/custom/index.html - but that converts a list. The command is the same though for list and single-item.